# Xcode does not see font in code but only in IB

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, fonts

I have few Montserrat font in my app and needed to add italic version of those font, i added them in project, target, info.plist and everywhere it is needed.

When i got to print font names i only see font i had previously

```
- 0 : "Montserrat-Regular"
- 1 : "Montserrat-Medium"
- 2 : "Montserrat-Light"
- 3 : "Montserrat-SemiBold"
```

Odd this is when i set italic font in IB to any label then it is showed in code

```
- 0 : "Montserrat-Regular"
- 1 : "Montserrat-Medium"
- 2 : "Montserrat-Light"
- 3 : "Montserrat-SemiBold"
- 4 : "Montserrat-LightItalic"
- 5 : "Montserrat-Italic"
```

If i have those fonts in IB UIFont(name: "Montserrat-LightItalic", size: size) will work, but if i remove it from IB it will not find the font.

I use .otf fonts, tried .ttf with same result. I tried to clean project, restart Xcode, deleted app from phone etc. I test on iOS 12 and Xcode is 10.1. Also tried on simulators, iPhone X and iPhone SE(10.2).

Anyone had similar issue or knows why is this happening.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. While adding font in Info.plist file it was added only to one target, not to all. So just tapped on target, went to info and added font there.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure why it is not working. Best potential guess is that maybe you called it something or referenced it, and the name in code is not actually the name. You can do

```
UIFont.familyNames.forEach({ familyName in
        let fontNames = UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: familyName)
        print(familyName, fontNames)
    })
```

to print out all the fonts and see if it shows up in code. If it is in IB, it should be available programatically. I would run this and see if your fonts appear.

Comment: Yes, and if i have them in IB i have them here, if they are not in IB they are not here. Not sure why or how.